# PHP LDAP Display Users Telephone Number / Attribute

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to get the basics of LDAP attributes (or at least I think that's what I am after). I have been able to successfully bind using the script below. I am now trying to get certain things to display. For Example, the users telephone number, which I believe is attribute homePhone. What code do I need to append here to get that to display?

```
$adServer = 'ldap://localhost';
$ds = ldap_connect($adServer, 53859); //non SSL

$dn = 'CN=Tony,CN=Users,DC=PropertyCoordinator,DC=net';
$password = 'Welcome1';

ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $password);
```

Update: I was able to add the below code:

```
$filter="(|(sn=Tony*)(givenname=Tony*))";
$justthese = array("homePhone");

$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);

$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
```

A var_dump($info) returns the following array

```
array(2) {
["count"] => int(1)[0] => array(4) {
    ["homephone"] => array(2) {
        ["count"] => int(1)[0] => string(10)
        "4132374026"
    }[0] => string(9)
    "homephone" ["count"] => int(1)["dn"] => string(47)
    "CN=Tony,CN=Users,DC=PropertyCoordinators,DC=net"
}
}
```

I know it would be something similar to echo $info[0][?];

Final Update and Answer:

```
echo $info[0]["homephone"][0];
```

Comment: to get it to display where? On a webpage or within AD Users&Computers?

Comment: Through just a simple echo.